# Using COUNTIFS with multiple options from cell references

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, countif

I found a similar formula to the below in this forum and it works brilliantly (thank you!) but I'm wondering if "Training A" and "Training B" can be replaced with cell references instead of specific words? The reason being, at some stage down the track our training requirements are likely to change (e.g. Training A may be completed and Training C introduced) so it would be ideal if our users can simply update the headings instead of formulas needing updating.

So, more specifically, what I'm hoping is that "Training A" can be replaced with a reference to cell `C21`, and "Training B" with a reference to cell `J21`. I've only included 2x here, but there are currently 8x training headings that would be incorporated into the final formula. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"Training A","Training B"}))
```

To put it into context, it would help simplify the reporting of completed training (%) for each of our 31 sites (listed in Reporting cells B4:B19). 8 headings are in Reporting rows 21, 55, 89 & 123 (2 each row, columns C & J) that relate to training modules in the Data tab; additional modules in the Data need to be ignored. Maybe there's another solution altogether? I’d like to avoid helper tables, and arrays tend to slow our spreadsheets down considerably here for some reason, although I’m happy to try if an array is the cleanest solution.

This formula works:
    =(COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$21,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$21,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$55,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$55,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$89,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$89,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$123,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*")+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$123,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*"))/(COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$21)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$21)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$55)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$55)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$89)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$89)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$C$123)+COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,Reporting!$J$123))

This also works:
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*",Data!A:A,{"*Safety at ABCD*","ABCD Policies - Professional","ABCD Policies - Operational","COR - Staff Management - Basic Staff Management","COR - Staff Management - Advanced Staff Management","ABCD Group - General Safety Awareness"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,{"*Safety at ABCD*","ABCD Policies - Professional","ABCD Policies - Operational","COR - Staff Management - Basic Staff Management","COR - Staff Management - Advanced Staff Management","ABCD Group - General Safety Awareness"}))

If the above module names could be replaced by cell references it would be ideal:
    =SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*",Data!A:A,{C21,J21,C55,J55,C89,J89,C123,J123}))/SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,Reporting!B4,Data!A:A,{C21,J21,C55,J55,C89,J89,C123,J123}))

Comment: If there are only two possibilities then it doesn't seem too hard to use `=COUNTIFS(A:A,E1)+COUNTIFS(A:A,F1)` where E1 is the first and F1 is the second.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated, I provided a simplified example; there are currently 8x training headings and more may be added. I currently have the formula working as you've suggested but would much prefer the simplified formula above... if it can be adapted accordingly. Thanks for your help Jeeped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple possibilities (e.g. Training A-H) then you have two options.

Assumes that there is a list in range `A2:A17` and some items to look for in range `C2:C5`. E.g.:

### Option 1

Use an array formula - you need to enter it and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A17,C2:C5))
```

After you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> it will appear as:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A17,C2:C5))}
```

### Option 2

The other option which avoids using an array formula is to use `SUMPRODUCT` and multiply the array given by `COUNTIFS` by an array of `1`s which is given by the presence of inputs to the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A2:A17,C2:C5),--(C2:C5<>""))
```

[image]

So it's a trade off between array formulas and a slightly more complex non-array formula (which still works with arrays).

### Update

If the inputs are in a non-contiguous range of cells, I would propose creating a contiguous range of filters and linking those cells to the various other inputs around the workbook. Both the options work with a filter range that has blanks, or numbers or inputs that aren't values in the list that is the target of the `COUNTIF`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Robin! Would either of the above work if the training names are not listed together? The names I'd like the formula to check for are in cells C21,J21,C55,J55,C89,J89,C123,J123. Apologies, I was adding a lot more info to my initial question before seeing your answer. Maybe what I'm after is asking too much :-)

Comment: To do that I would simply use the contiguous range presented in the answer but make those cells just equal to the various other cells scattered on the worksheet. So my `C2` is hard-coded as `Training A` but could easily be `=C21` and point to whatever value is in that cell.

Comment: Thank you again @Robin! I'm a little brain dead right now so will try and get my head around this tomorrow. I'll let you know how I go :-)

Comment: thanks so much! I've used the sumproduct formula (very helpful, hadn’t used this before) and it works perfectly. Really appreciate your help:-)

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Data!$A:$A,Reporting!$C$21:$O$123,Data!$E:$E,Reporting!$B4,Data!$F:$F,"*complete*"),--(Reporting!$C$21:$O$123<>""))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Data!$A:$A,Reporting!$C$21:$O$123,Data!$E:$E,Reporting!$B4),--(Reporting!$C$21:$O$123<>""))